# Django sitemap - add loc into sitemap

Tags: django

is there a way to add a custom location into a sitemap? I would like to add my homepage into the sitemap, but I don't use `flatpages`.

Should I start using flatpages and manually add the homepage into the database? Which approach do you recommend? I use `django.contrib.sitemaps` to generate the site map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a sitemap for specific views, otherwise not included in the site's sitemap, as in the one below I have developed for my own Django application:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

class StaticSitemap(Sitemap):
    """Reverse static views for XML sitemap."""

    def __init__(self, items_in=[]):
        self.items_list = items_in

    def items(self):
        # Return list of url names for views to include in sitemap
        return self.items_list

    def location(self, item):
        # if kwargs not in item set as None
        kwargs = item['kwargs'] if 'kwargs' in item else None
        return reverse(item['view_name'], kwargs=kwargs)
```

Basically this reverses the view names (as specified in the `urls.py`) into their actual URLs that will be shown in the sitemap.

**Usage**

Specify your `sitemap.xml` URL in `urls.py` so that it takes a `sitemaps` parameter as in the `urls.py` extract below:

```
...
(
    r'^sitemap\.xml$',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
    {'sitemaps': sitemaps}
),
...
```

the `sitemaps` dict should simply include an entry such as:

```
sitemaps = {
    'views': StaticSitemap(STATIC_VIEWS),
    ...
}
```

where `STATIC_VIEWS` is constructed in this way:

```
STATIC_URLS = [
    'home_page', 'about_page', 'disclaimer_page', # any other view name
]
STATIC_VIEWS = []
for url in STATIC_URLS:
    STATIC_VIEWS.append({'view_name':url})
```